# Bill alone cannot solve this problem

Tags: adjectives, punctuation, postpositive-adjectives

a. Bill alone cannot solve this problem. He needs help.

b. Bill alone cannot solve this problem. Everyone else in the class can.

Are both of the above grammatically correct?
Are they correctly punctuated?

In which case does one have to set off 'alone' with commas?

c. Bill, alone, cannot solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

They are both grammatically correct; they're using two different definitions of the adverb form.  See https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/alone#Adverb

Example "a" appears to be usage 2.  Example "b" looks like usage 3.3.

Whether they're correctly punctuated is a matter of opinion, I think, as it's your second sentence in each example that provides the context to resolve the ambiguity.  You might opt to replace the usage in example "b" with something like "Only Bill is unable to solve this problem".